# Repeated Substring Pattern

Tags: algorithms, strings, python, substrings

I've been working on the following challenge on LeetCode:

---

**Problem:**
Given a string s, check if it can be constructed by taking a substring of it and appending multiple copies of the substring together.

---

During my exploration, I stumbled upon an interesting solution:

```
def repeatedSubstringPattern(s: str) -> bool:
    return s in (s + s)[1:-1]
```

I'm working to comprehend why this solution works.

Firstly, let's consider a string $x$ that can be constructed with a repeated substring pattern. In this case, $x$ takes the form:

$$x=SS\dots S$$

where $S$ is not an empty string, and there are more than two occurrences of $S$.

Now, if we concatenate two instances of $x$ and remove the first and last elements, we get:

$$y=ASS\dots SB$$

This string $y$ includes the original string $x$, and the function returns true.

However, I need to know how to demonstrate why the function returns false when the string does not have the specified form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of proving that the function returns false when the string is not of the specified form, let us use the contraposition.

Let $s = a_1…a_n$ be the string and assume that the function returns true. That means that $s$ is a substring of $a_2a_3…a_na_1a_2…a_{n-1}$. Since $s$ is of length $n$, that means that there exists $k\in\{2, …, n\}$ such that:
$$s = a_ka_{k+1}…a_na_1…a_{k-1}$$

Let $u = a_k…a_n$ and $v = a_1…a_{k-1}$. Then neither $u$ nor $v$ is empty and $s = uv = vu$.

Suppose (without loss of generality) that $|u| \leqslant |v|$ and let us prove by induction on $|u| + |v|$ that there exists $w$ and $m_1$, $m_2$ such that $u=w^{m_1}$ and $v = w^{m_2}$:

- if $|u| + |v| = 2$, then $u$ and $v$ are one-letter words and the result is direct with $w = u$ and $m_1 = m_2 = 1$;
- otherwise, since $uv = vu$ and $|u| \leqslant |v|$, that means that $u$ is a prefix of $v$, and there exists $v'$ such that $v = uv'$.

  - If $v' = \varepsilon$, then $w = u$ and $m_1 = m_2 = 1$ are suitable.
  - Otherwise $uuv' = uv'u$, so $uv' = v'u$. Using induction hypothesis, there exists $w$ and $m_1$ and $m_2'$ such that $u = w^{m_1}$ and $v' = w^{m_2'}$. Then $v = uv' = w^{m_1+m_2'}$.

Since $s = uv$, then $s = w^{m_1+m_2}$, and $w$ is a proper substring of $s$, because $m_1 +m_2 > 1$.